# validate name using regex in yui textbox containing alphabet numbrt apostphy hyphen and space

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, yui

I want to validate name of a user with folowing condition.

It must contain alphabet and can contain number apostphy ('), hyphen(-) and white space and also validate first character should always be aplhabet nothing else

i want to use regex for that.

please suggest i have tried following regex:

```
/^[a-z\d\-_\s]+$/i
```

Apart from those three special character it shouldnt be accepting any special character

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is okay, but to make sure the first character is alphabet, you need to do this:

```
/^[a-zA-Z][0-9A-Za-z-'\\s]+$/i
  ^^^^^^^^
```

The reason for this, is because a character class `[]` creates a **set** of characters that can be matched. There is no order.

Also make sure to put hyphens as the last character in the class, or it will turn into a range.

Comment: you have forgot the apostph in your character class

Comment: your regex also take 1st letter as an interger value

Comment: @Vasli Syrakis  this is not working for me i tried [^0-9A-Za-z-'\\s] this works but its accepting first character as number